# Object.entries is giving only first object

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my object

```
var obj = {
"first_obj": {
    "a":1,
    "status": 1
},
"second_obj": {
    "a":2,
    "status": 3
 }
}
```

I am trying to iterate through this object using foreach and on object.entries but my object.entries is giving me only first object?

```
console.log(Object.entries(obj)) = [
[
    "$init",
    true
],
[
    "first_obj",
    {
        "a": 1,
        "status": 1
    }
]
];
```

Why is it not giving me the second object and how can I get my second object?

```js
var obj = {
"first_obj": {
    "a":1,
    "status": 1
},
"second_obj": {
    "a":2,
    "status": 3
 }
}
console.log(Object.entries(obj));
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem, snippet seems to work fine (and neither `$init` nor `true` are anywhere in your input)

Comment: I am getting this output

Comment: what you want ??

Comment: Your code snippet is working fine

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by adding `obj.toJSON();` because Mongoose was not giving me the required result in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) works fine in your code example.

I think you want to iterate over your object `key`s, and for that you can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
const obj = {
  "first_obj": {
    "a":1,
    "status": 1
  },
  "second_obj": {
    "a":2,
    "status": 3
   }
};


Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
  console.log(`${k}: a = ${obj[k].a}, status = ${obj[k].status}`);
});
```